# How can I print the contents of a list stored in database, one by one?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog on my own and wanted to figure out how to print the contents of a list stored in a database, one by one.

My thought is that if I open (consult) this in SWI-Prolog, I can then run the code using `go().` and get it to output the values in the valueslist.

```
valueslist(['papua new guinea',botswana,'netherlands antilles',sweden,cameroon]).

printlist([]).
printlist([X|List]) :-
  write(X),nl,
  printlist(List).

go :-
  write('Here is an example list of countries: '), nl,
  printlist(valueslist).
```

As it is right now the code just prints `Here is an example list of countries:` followed by `false.`

What I wanted it to do is print that `Here us an example...` followed by the countries list like

```
papua new guinea
botswana
netherlands antilles
sweden
cameroon
```

How would one properly do accomplish something like this in Prolog?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found an answer by continuing to tinker with it. I am not sure if this is a good way to do it in Prolog but it is giving the output I hoped for.

The code that prints out the list looks like so:

```
valueslist(['papua new guinea',botswana,'netherlands antilles',sweden,cameroon]).

printlist([]).
printlist([X|List]) :-
  write(X),nl,
  printlist(List).

go :-
  write('Here is an example list of countries: '), nl,
  valueslist(List),
  printlist(List).
```

Comment: This is exactly how it should be done, well done!

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie hmm hmm. For side effects it would be better to use a failure driven loop, or its better equivalent, `forall/2`. `forall(member(X, List), writeln(X))`

Comment: That would be an alternative. One that's new and unintuitive for beginners. Why would it be *better*? And why not `maplist(writeln, List)` if we really want to hide the iteration?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I don't want to hide anything. All three: 1. maplist 2. forall and 3. classic failure driven loop with `repeat, ( ..., fail ; true )` behave differently when it comes to failure and backtracking. So you need to pick the right one depending on the exact need. _For side effects in particular_ forall is _usually_ the best fit.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie "unintuitive for beginners" _please_ let's not go there. Intuition has its place in math, science, and even computer programming, but its importance is terribly overestimated.